# How do I remove all characters after a certain one, inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

my problem is:

I have a list which, after numerous cleanup, features elements which looks like '455XYZ455'. I'm trying to remove everything after X, but it is inside a list. The code that allows me to do this is the following:

```
check = [re.sub(r'\W', '', i) for i in content]
# print(check)
check2 = [re.sub('[aclassnewpagehref]', '', i) for i in check]
# print(check2)
check3 = [re.sub('[/<=""]', '', i) for i in check2]
# print(check3)
check4 = [item for item in check3 if item != '']
print(check4)
```

As expected it gives me just like above, a lot of '455XYZ455'. I just want the '455', but this is a list.
Being a complete beginner in Python, I am entirely stuck.
Thank you for reading and perhaps helping me!

Comment: your code doesn't seem any close to solve the issue you are describing... are you sure of yourself?

Comment: honestly, my code is a bit (very) messy, after checking it, this one is used to grab elements that are only with a certain length. My bad. It is one of the many little bits of code I used to clear up the mess that's my list.

Comment: suggest you to fix that and edit your question so people treat your question seriously... anyway good luck and welcome to python world!

Comment: i just did! thank you pal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the first digits in group 1 that you want to keep and remove the rest starting from X.

```
\A(\d+)X.*\Z
```

**Explanation**

- `\A` Start of string
- `(\d+)X` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1**, then match X
- `.*\Z` Match any char 0+ times and assert the end of the string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6zCYg/1)

For example

```
import re
final = ["455XYZ455", "455XYZ455"]
for item in final:
    print(re.sub(r"^(\d+)X.*\Z", r"\1", item))
```

Output

```
455
455
```

Comment: Actually there's already a bit of regex in my code. I will edit my post to show you the code that is really used to filter the list.

Comment: awesome answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by using split without regex.Suppose the string  '455XYZ455' is in variable a.

```
s = a.split('x')[0]
```

Here a will be split by 'x' and it will return the list of parts before and after 'x' but as you need just the part before 'x' , I've assigned the first element of list to s.